# CDI deployment failure:WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, cdi, bean-validation, openjpa

While migrating an application from Glassfish 3.1.2.2 to Glassfish 4.1 to Glassfish 5.1 I came across an ambigous dependency issue.
The error log looked like this:

```
[Payara 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=141 _ThreadName=admin-thread-pool::admin-listener(8)] [timeMillis: 1588867965816] [levelValue: 1000] [[
  Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator
  at org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator(BValInterceptor.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - org.apache.bval.cdi.ValidatorBean@526d08fd,
  - ValidatorBean [id=org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidatorBean_default]

org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [UnbackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator
  at org.apache.bval.cdi.BValInterceptor.validator(BValInterceptor.java:0)
  Possible dependencies: 
  - org.apache.bval.cdi.ValidatorBean@526d08fd,
  - ValidatorBean [id=org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidatorBean_default]
```

I did parallel tests on Payara 4.1 and Payara 5.1, because some misleading hints were suggesting that it is the server platform that causes the issue.

However, the problem in my case was, that a `openjpa-all-2.4.3.jar` was referenced. This jar includes all packages required to use all features of OpenJPA, sadly also the `org.apache.bval.cdi.ValidatorBean`. Just for reference, for Glassfish 4.1 and Glassfish 5 I had already updated to `openjpa-all-3.1.0.jar`. While including the `openjpa-all-*.jar` did not seem to be a problem in Glassfish 3 (java ee 6) environment, because the packages provided by the java ee server were distinct from the ones included in the application, it became a problem on Glassfish/Payara 4.* , and also on Glassfish/Payara 5.*, because those servers already provide some of the packages.

The most important parts of those log entries are therefore `org.apache.bval.cdi.ValidatorBean` and `ValidatorBean [id=org.hibernate.validator.internal.cdi.ValidatorBean_default]`. One of those packages/namespaces is loaded twice. In my case the `org.apache.bval.cdi.ValidatorBean` was already provided by a jar on the java ee server, respectively `bean-validator-cdi.jar` on Glassfish 4.*, and 5.* .

[image: Comparing the two packages/jar files]

**So the solution here is** to just include the `openjpa-3.1.0.jar` and the required references for the project (you'll find those in the openjpa zip file under libs. In my case and for this project, those were `serp-1.15.1.jar`, `xbean-asm7-shaded-4.12.jar`, and `commons-collections4-4.3.jar`.

I guess this whole issue happens mostly, when an own JPA Library (hybernate, openjpa, etc.) is used, instead of the default library on the java ee server. Similar when a dependency already includes several other packages, that might also be provided by an existing dependency or by a library provided by the server.

I also tried the `asadmin set configs.config.server-config.cdi-service.enable-implicit-cdi=false` approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003014/glassfish-4-1-cdi-weld-001409-ambiguous-dependencies), and also the idea of prioritizing certain classloaders over other as described in the [glassfish/payara documentation](https://payara.gitbooks.io/payara-server/documentation/payara-server/classloading.html) , but those just move the issue to another level, and do not solve the issue at hand. E.g., if you run multiple applications, those settings will likely have an impact on other applications on the same server as well.

Also, if you see people writing about the idea/intent of unpacking/editing/alter/repacking standard jars on the server, please stop them. It is a terrible idea. It will work once for the given application, and whoever takes over the project, server, etc. will one day step into this trap and search forever. Who would guess that someone altered the standard jar files provided by an application server. Maybe after reading this comment here... ;)

Similar issues, which were of some help:

- [Unsatisfied dependencies for type [...] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point (using @Stateful EJB with CDI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10346285/unsatisfied-dependencies-for-type-with-qualifiers-default-at-injection/10389371)
- [WELD-SE + JUnit5 WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type Validator with qualifiers @Default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57143276/weld-se-junit5-weld-001409-ambiguous-dependencies-for-type-validator-with-qua)
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BVAL-152

Remaining Questions:

- Is it possible to autodetect the jar file that provides a or the conflicting package?

Comment: Why not update the server with newer or different jpa instead of providing a newer jpa in your project?

Comment: @Kukeltje because first step is to migrate, and then improvements can be introduced, e.g., upgrading the jpa classes/frameworks. This code was not written well, there are a lot of issues. So one step at a time. Ok, and upgrading the server is only possible if I own it. So when I share the app, it shall run without changing the standard server. Makes it easier for everyone using it.

Comment: Sometimes (often) you better bite the apple improve directly. Might be simpler than trying to migrate things that might in the end turn out to be migratable.

Comment: Assuming you are using maven, did you try to exclude from your openjpa-all dependency the bval validator?